# Pauses Between Google App Engine Tasks

Tags: google-app-engine, queue

Every minute, a cron job adds around 6 tasks to my default queue. Each task takes around 3 seconds to run.

I would like the items to be processed one after the other without any pause between them. However, App Engine can wait up to a minute between calling a task.  I only want 1 task to run at a time.

How can I prevent this gap?

My queue.yaml file looks like this:

```
queue:
- name: default
  rate: 10/s
  max_concurrent_requests: 1
  bucket_size: 100
  retry_parameters:
    task_age_limit: 2m
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding all tasks at once and relying on the queue to schedule them sequentially, you can chain tasks together by calling [Task.add()](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/tasks#Task_add) from inside the task itself to add the next one once it's done. You may need to relax 'max_concurrent_requests' to allow more than one task to execute to account for the overlap.